# how do we get the following output?

Tags: c, casting

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{ 
    int i = 258;
    char ch = i;
    printf("%d", ch)
}
```

the output is 2!

How the range of variable works? what is the range of different data types in c langauge?

Comment: @JanTuroň this is not an overflow, welcome to C.

Answer (score 4):

When assigning to a smaller type the value is

- truncated, i.e. `258 % 256` if the new type is unsigned
- modified in an implementation-defined fashion if the new type is signed

> Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by
>   **repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that
>   can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of
>   the new type**.
>
> Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented
>   in it; either the result is implementation-deﬁned or an
>   implementation-deﬁned signal is raised.

So all that fancy "adding or subtracting" means it is assigned as if you said:

```
ch = i % 256;
```

Comment: @ouah How can you tell ? As far as I see, `ch` could be either signed or unsigned since the OP didn't specify.

Comment: well, right you cannot. But it is likely to be as `char` is signed on most platforms.

Answer (score 3):

`char` is 8-bit long, while `258` requires nine bits to represent. Converting to `char` chops off the most significant bit of `258` which is `100000010` in binary, resulting in `10`, which is `2` in binary.

When you pass `char` to `printf`, it gets *promoted* to `int`, which is then picked up by the `%d` format specifier, and printed as `2`.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{ 
    int i = 258;
    char ch = i;
    printf("%d", ch)
}
```

Here `i` is `0000000100000010` on the machine level. `ch` takes 1 byte, so it takes last 8 bit, it is `00000010`, it is 2.

Answer (score 1):

In order to find out how long various types are in C language you should refer to limits.h (or climits in C++). char is not guaranteed to be 8 bits long . It is just:

> smallest addressable unit of the machine that can contain basic character set. It is an integer type. Actual type can be either signed or unsigned depending on implementation

Same sort of vague definitions are put for other types.

Alternatively, you can use operator `sizeof` to dynamically find out size of the type in bytes.

You may not assume exact ranges of native C data types. Standard places only minimal restrictions, so you can say `unsigned short` can hold at least 65536 different values. Upper limit can differ

Refer to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types) for more reading

Answer (score 1):

char is on **8 bits** so, when you cast (you assign an integer to a char), in **32 bits** machine, the i (int is on 32 bits) var is:

```
00000000 00000000 00000001 00000010 = 258 (in binary)
```

When you want a char from this int, you truncate the last 8 bits (char is on 8 bits), so you get:

**00000010 which mean 2 in decimal**, this is why you see this output.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

This is an **overflow** ; the result is undefined because `char` may be `signed` (undefined behavior) or `unsigned` (well-defined "wrap-around" behavior).

Answer (score 0):

You are using **little-endian** machine.

Binary representation of 258 is

```
00000000 00000000 00000001 00000010
```

while assigning integer to char, only 8 byte of data is copied to char. i.e LSB.

Here only `00000010` i.e 0x02 will be copied to char.

The same code will gives zero, in case of **big-endian** machine.